# how to access an text value

Tags: javascript, html

in the following piece of code i want to access input text box value using your id. but it's throwing an object error.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
function test()
{
 var a1 = document.getElementById(i1);

 alert(a1);
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id= 'test1'>
<div id = 'test2'>
        <input id = 'i1' type = 'text' name='i1' value='random'>
        <input type='button' value="click me" onclick="test()">

    </div>
</div>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a1 = document.getElementById(i1);
```

change to

```
var a1 = document.getElementById('i1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes, also to get value you should use `.value`.

```
function test() {
 var a1 = document.getElementById("i1").value;    
 alert(a1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var a1 = document.getElementById("i1");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example1**

```
function test() {
 var a1 = document.getElementById('i1').value;    
 alert(a1);
}
```

**Example2**

```
<input type='button' value="click me" onclick="test(document.getElementById('i1').value)">

 function test(a1) {
  alert(a1);
}
```

**FULL HTML CODE**

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
   <script>
    function test()
    {
    var a1 = document.getElementById('i1').value;

    alert(a1);
    }
   </script>
   </HEAD>

   <BODY>
   <div id= 'test1'>
   <div id = 'test2'>
    <input id = 'i1' type = 'text' name='i1' value='random'>
    <input type='button' value="click me" onclick="test()">

  </div>
  </div>

 </BODY>
 <HTML>
```

Comment: You're missing the quotes document.getElementById("i1")

Answer (score 0):

change

> ```
> var a1 = document.getElementById(i1);
> ```

to this

> var a1 = document.getElementById(i1).value;

OR you can change

> alert(a1);

to

> alert(a1.value);